# Error in getting tab host in my activity

Tags: android

when i am trying to get the tab host which id is  `@android:id/tabhost` in my `activity_main` Layout. and trying to call in my activity which extends the fragment activity in this way

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost); 
tabHost.setup();
```

then it showing the error  Did you forget to call

```
'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two `setup()` method.. other is `setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)`
If you are using `setContent(android.content.Intent)`, this must be called since the activityGroup is needed to launch the local activity.
just replace `setup()` method with `setup(this.getLocalActivityManager())` hope it works.....
see [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html)

Comment: @Tamin   i am beginner in android and i am not using  setContent(android.content.Intent) and when i am using setup(this.getLocalActivityManager()) it is showing to make that method.

Comment: @Tamin  yes my code is  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360054/tabhost-error-in-getting-in-to-my-activity